# log4j2 properties file example using jvm arguments configured using enviroment

Tags: log4j2, jvm-arguments

I am using exec $CF_JAVADIR/bin/java -Dconvertfile.propertiesfile=$CF_PROPERTIES_FILE -Dlog4j.configurationFile=$CF_LOG4J_CONFIG_FILE com.convert.StartConvert >>$LOGFILE 2>&1

Log4j2 is trying to read it as an xml cofiguration.
How to specify it to be a properties file

Getting below error
[Fatal Error] TKUat1_Log4j.cf:1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
ERROR StatusLogger Error parsing /opt/pt/convertfile/convertfil_tk.65/etc/TKUat1_Log4j.cf
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A [`ConfigurationFactory`](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/config/ConfigurationFactory.html) uses the file's extension to decide if it can parse the file. The XML factory is the only one that allows any extension.

Therefore you just need to call the file `TKUat1_Log4j.properties`.

Alternatively you can force Log4j to use a single `ConfigurationFactory`. In your case just use:

```
-Dlog4j2.configurationFactory=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.properties.PropertiesConfigurationFactory
```